# Saving images to a database or filesystem on iPhone

Tags: iphone

What is the best approach if I want to some of the rows in my database table to have an image. Should I add an column with type BLOB, or should I just keep a reference to the image and add the image in the documents folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are both advantages and disadvantages to storing image data (or other large chunks of binary data) in a database. On the upside:

- All of the app's data could be contained within a single file
- Depending on the database, you may have the option of transactional/atomic updates to the app's data, avoiding problems where app data gets into unexpected states during error conditions

The disadvantages are:

- The DB will be larger
- There may be optimizations that are associated with working with image data from a filesystem that will be lost (e.g. - memory mapping)
- The memory footprint for working with images may be increased
- Depending on the DB granularity during writes, there may be increased contention/blocking which decreases the speed at which the DB could be updated if one wanted to make a lot of separate, transactional/atomic changes quickly

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is saving just a reference.
1. your DB would be much smaller.
2. It is more flexible: you can change your image  to another one (with the same name) without updating the DB.